# Javaのジェネリクスでユニオン型をextendsするようなことがしたい

Tags: java, java8

Javaのジェネリクスについて型を指定するときに(TypeScriptのUnion型のように)"String型またはLong型"というような型の指定はできないのでしょうか？

イメージ（？）

```
class Test<T extends String | extends Long>{
 ......
}
```

Comment: 参考: [Is there a Java equivalent for Typescript union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555753/is-there-a-java-equivalent-for-typescript-union)

Answer (score 0):

Java はそもそも多重継承できないので、あるクラス T が複数クラスを extends することはできないので、ジェネリクスで指定する T にしてもその原則に従うはずです。

なので、ジェネリクスでは extends 一つと、implements（複数も可）を組み合わせた

```
class Test<T extends ClassA & InterfaceB & InterfaceC>{
 ......
}
```

みたいな形式ならば可能（参考：[Bounded Type Parameters: Multiple Bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)）である一方、複数クラスを指定する方法はないということでしょう。